# QWizard possible memory leak

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm making a wizard that upon performing a certain task launches another program and closes itself. It seems to be working fine. However, once I run it through Valgrind it gave me a possible memory leak on a line where I assign wizard pages. It also gives me a rather huge message (around 2,5k lines) into the console.

Here is the simple program which replicates the problem

**mainwizard.cpp**

```
MainWizard::MainWizard(QWidget *parent) :
QWizard(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWizard)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWizardStyle(QWizard::ClassicStyle);
    //This line gives me a Valgrind warning
    setPage(0,  new WizardPage());
}

MainWizard::~MainWizard()
{
    qDebug() << "end";
    delete ui;
}

void MainWizard::TerminateWizard()
{
    QString program = "../GrafonTest/GrafonTest";
    QStringList arguments;

    QProcess *desktop_process = new QProcess();

    desktop_process->startDetached(program, arguments);
    done(0);
}
```

**wizardpage.cpp**

```
WizardPage::WizardPage(QWidget *parent) :
    QWizardPage(parent),
    ui(new Ui::WizardPage)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(FinishWizard()));
}

WizardPage::~WizardPage()
{
    delete ui;
}

void WizardPage::initializePage()
{
    MainWizard *pWizard = (MainWizard*)wizard();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(timeToEndWizard()), pWizard, SLOT(TerminateWizard()));
}


void WizardPage::FinishWizard()
{
    emit timeToEndWizard();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWizard w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I tried making the pages separate members of the wizard class and the result was the same.
If I don't call QProcess, there are no errors. Likewise if I comment the setpage line and close the wizard by timer or something else.

Where is the error?

EDIT. valgrind complains even if I don't close the wizard in TerminateWizard(). He does so in the moment I press the button. And however many times I press it the amount of bytes possibly lost is the same

Comment: You never delete your `QProcess` object. `QProcess::startDetached` is also a static member so you don't need an object there.

Comment: I tried that too, nothing changed. And calling the static function didn't lead to any improvements. Also, if I don't call setPage() function Valgrind gives me no complaints whatsoever

Comment: Valgrind may not believe that setPage takes ownership of the page

Comment: But if I try to run the wizard without starting a process, there are no errors